# How to duplicate Delphi's swap function in c#

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write a swap function in C# to mimic the one in Delphi. According to the documentation the one in Delphi will do the following:

- If the number is two bytes, bytes 1 and 2 are swapped
- if the number is four bytes, bytes 1 and 4 are swapped, bytes 2 and 3 remain where they are

Below is the code I have.

```
int number = 17665024;
var hi = (byte)(number >> 24);
var lo = (byte)(number & 0xff);
return (number & 0x00FFFF00) + (lo & 0xFF000000) + (hi & 0x000000FF);
```

Some numbers seem to return what I expect, but most do not.

```
// Value in        // Expected         // Actual
17665024           887809              887809
5376               21                  5376
-30720             136                 16746751
3328               13                  3328
```

It's probably a fairly obvious mistake to most, but I haven't dealt with bitwise shift operators much and I cannot seem to work out what I have done wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hold on, bytes 1 and 2 are swapped but bytes 2 and 3 remain where they are? There's something wrong there

Comment: Typo - nice spotting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, the data types `short` and `int` correspond to integral data types of 2 bytes and 4 bytes, respectively.  The algorithm above applies to int (4 bytes).

This algorithm contains an error: `(lo & 0xFF000000)` will always return 0 because `lo` is a byte.  What you probably intended was `lo << 24`, which shifts `lo` 24 bytes to the left.

For an `int` data type, the proper function then becomes:

```
    int SwapInt(int number)
    {
        var hi = (byte)(number >> 24);
        var lo = (byte)(number & 0xff);
        return ((number & 0xffff00) | (lo << 24) | hi);
    }
```

For a `short` data type, the middle term disappears and we are left with simply:

```
    short SwapShort(short number)
    {
        var hi = (byte)(number >> 8);
        var lo = (byte)(number & 0xff);
        return (short)((lo << 8) | hi);
    }
```

Then `Swap((short)5376)` returns the expected value of 21.  Note that `Swap(5376)` will use the default `int` datatype for 5376, which returns 5376.  To treat integers that can be wholly expressed in two bytes as `short`, you can run:

```
   int Swap(int n)
   {
        if (n >= Short.MinValue && n <= Short.MaxValue)
              return SwapShort((short)n);
        else
              return SwapInt(n);
   }
```